# Flutter Plugin Android Dependency Cannot Resolve

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-plugin

I am creating a new plugin for flutter, which requires

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
```

cannot resolve the above

i have tried many things to implement the library, but no success. i have attached the screenshot also 
Gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}




apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    dependencies{
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    }
}

dependencies{
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In [project]/android/app/build.gradle: 

    // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: i cant use that, because it requires the json file provided by Firebase, and i dont need that